# How to remove a plugin configuration defined in parent pom from child pom

Tags: maven, maven-3, pom.xml, parent-pom

I have a parent pom defining in pluginManagement some configuration items for a plugin in which there is a particular one config. that I do not want in child pom.

I tried overriding other configuration items in my child pom, which worked, but "removing" a configuration item didn't seem to work. By "removing" I mean I tried not filling in anything, e.g.:

```
<configuration>
  <itemIdontWant></itemIdontWant>
</configuration>
```

The above didn't work and I still got the same config. in the compilation process. I can fill in some garbage to void the effect of this item, but I want the proper way to "remove" it. Any help?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can simply try the following:

```xml
<configuration>
  <itemIdontWant combine.self="override"></itemIdontWant>
</configuration>
```

The problem with the above could be that if you like to set it to empty the defaults of the plugin will become the value.

Furthermore you can change the inheritance of the configuration by using:

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <inherited>false</inherited>
      <groupId>...</groupId>
      <artifactId>..</artifactId>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

The documentation of the above parts can be found here: https://maven.apache.org/pom.html

Comment: Yay the additional combine.self="override" worked. Any reason why this is not needed if you have value redefined but is needed when you set an empty value?

Comment: which config does the inherited tag go into, the parent or the child?  The Apache docs don't indicate which either.